# How Angular dist folder(After build) works with multiple projects

Tags: angular, build

I am creating angular project, to optimize build time I am split the application into 3 applications, App1, App2 and App3. To test in my local after building 3 projects individually I am coping the App2 and App3 main.js files into App1(dist/app1_main/main.js and dist/app2_main/main.js). How can I write routing in App1 to load a component which is in App2 and App3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for a more robust Angular architecture. You can achieve this utilizing a multi-project workspace where you can create libraries that share components between applications, and also you can create common services. Please take a look at https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects

Here is great documentation about this architecture https://octoperf.com/blog/2019/08/22/kraken-angular-workspace-multi-application-project/

Comment: Thanks alot. This is what exatly I am looking for. BTW will this multi-project architecture optimize the build time?

Comment: The great thing about this approach is that you don't need to build all your code at once like mono-repo. Dev-ops can focus on one app build and deployment without touching other apps that don't have anything to do with the update.